# Adding Column to data frame based on list content in a loop? - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, data-manipulation

I'm pulling data from the NHL API for player stats based on individual games. I'm trying to make a loop that calls the data, parses the JSON, creates a dict which I then can create a data frame from for an entire team. The code before my looping looks like this:

```
API_URL = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1"

response = requests.get(API_URL + "/people/8477956/stats?stats=gameLog", params={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

data = json.loads(response.text)

df_list_dict = []
for game in data['stats'][0]['splits']:
  curr_dict = game['stat']
  curr_dict['date'] = game['date']
  curr_dict['isHome'] = game['isHome']
  curr_dict['isWin'] = game['isWin']
  curr_dict['isOT'] = game['isOT']
  curr_dict['team'] = game['team']['name']
  curr_dict['opponent'] = game['opponent']['name']

  df_list_dict.append(curr_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_list_dict)
print(df)
```

This gives me a digestible data frame for a single player. (/people/{player}/....

I want to iterate through a list (the list being an NHL team), while adding a column that identifies the player and concatenates the created data frames. My attempt thus far looks like this:

```
import requests 
import json
import pandas as pd

Rangers  = ['8478550', '8476459', '8479323', '8476389', '8475184', '8480817', '8480078', '8476624', '8481554', '8482109', '8476918', '8476885', '8479324', 
'8482073', '8479328', '8480833', '8478104', '8477846', '8477380', '8477380', '8477433', '8479333', '8479991']


def callapi(player):
    response = (requests.get(f'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/{player}/stats?stats=gameLog', params={"Content-Type": "application/json"}))
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    df_list_dict = []
    for game in data['stats'][0]['splits']:
        curr_dict = game['stat']
        curr_dict['date'] = game['date']
        curr_dict['isHome'] = game['isHome']
        curr_dict['isWin'] = game['isWin']
        curr_dict['isOT'] = game['isOT']
        curr_dict['team'] = game['team']['name']
        curr_dict['opponent'] = game['opponent']['name']
        
        df_list_dict.append(curr_dict)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_list_dict)
    print(df)

for player in Rangers:  
    callapi(player)
    print(callapi)
```

When this is printed I can see all the data frames that were created. I cannot use curr_dict[] to add a column based on the list position (the player ID) because must be a slice or integer, not string.

What I'm hoping to do is make this one data frame in which the stats are identified by a player id column.

My python knowledge is very scattered, I feel as if with the progress I've made I should know how to complete this but I've simply hit a wall. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to parallelize the requests before concatenating them all together, and [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to parse the json.

```
import concurrent.futures
import json
import os

import pandas as pd
import requests


class Scrape:
    def main(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        rangers = ["8478550", "8476459", "8479323", "8476389", "8475184", "8480817", "8480078",
                   "8476624", "8481554", "8482109", "8476918", "8476885", "8479324", "8482073",
                   "8479328", "8480833", "8478104", "8477846", "8477380", "8477380", "8477433",
                   "8479333", "8479991"]

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
            return pd.concat(executor.map(self.get_stats, rangers)).reset_index(drop=True).fillna(0)

    @staticmethod
    def get_stats(player: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        url = f"https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/{player}/stats?stats=gameLog"

        with requests.Session() as request:
            response = request.get(url, timeout=30)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(response.raise_for_status())

        data = json.loads(response.text)

        df = (pd.
              json_normalize(data=data, record_path=["stats", "splits"])
              .rename(columns={"team.id": "team_id", "team.name": "team_name",
                               "opponent.id": "opponent_id", "opponent.name": "opponent_name"})
              ).assign(player_id=player)

        df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex="link|gamePk")))]
        df.columns = df.columns.str.split(".").str[-1]

        if "faceOffPct" not in df.columns:
            df["faceOffPct"] = 0

        return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stats = Scrape().main()
    print(stats)
```